# how to make vertical lines touch the boundaries of the chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like the vertical lines I create with `ax.vlines` to touch the upper and lower bounds of my chart, in the same manner as `axvline` does.

Consider this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : [pd.to_datetime('2016-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2016-01-03'), pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04')],
                   'value1' : [1, 2, 3],
                   'value2' : [10, 20, 30]})

df.set_index('time', inplace = True)

df
Out[95]: 
            value1  value2
time                      
2016-01-02       1      10
2016-01-03       2      20
2016-01-04       3      30
```

Now the chart is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15))

ax.plot(df.index, df["value1"], color = 'black')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index, df["value2"], color = 'red')

#axvline stretches nicely
ax.axvline( pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04'), color = 'red',  alpha = 1,  linestyle = '--')

#vlines stops before touching the upper and lower boundaries
ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()
ax.vlines([pd.to_datetime('2016-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2016-01-03')],  ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, color = 'blue', linestyle = '-')
```

gives :

[image]

You can see those blue lines remain in the air, while the nice red vertical line stretches completely. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to `set_ylim` so the axis won't change when you plot `vlines`. Add `ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)` before the `ax.vlines(...)` line.

One minor thing is that you might want to plot `vlines` on the `ax2` since you used `ymin, ymax` from `ax2`. Therefore, I updated your code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2016-01-02'),
                            pd.to_datetime('2016-01-03'),
                            pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04')],
                   'value1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'value2': [10, 20, 30]})
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15))
ax.plot(df.index, df["value1"], color='black')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index, df["value2"], color='red')

#axvline stretches nicely
ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04'), color = 'red',
           alpha = 1,  linestyle = '--')

#vlines stretches nicely
ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax2.vlines([pd.to_datetime('2016-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2016-01-03')],
           ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color='blue', linestyle='-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: will that work with the dual axis as well? does it work in this example?

Comment: Yes, it works on `ax2`. Updated my answer. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: well it actually does not work because the black line now disappears from the chart

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Uploaded new graph for everything on `ax2`. The black line overlaps with the red line. That's why I suspect you want to plot `vlines` on `ax2` instead of `ax`, since `ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)` will hide the black line.

Answer (score 7):

What you probably want to do is make the blue lines independent of the data in y direction. This can be done using the `xaxis_transform` and setting the ymin and ymax to 0 and 1 respectively.

```
ax.vlines([pd.to_datetime('2016-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2016-01-03')],  
           ymin = 0, ymax = 1, color = 'blue', linestyle = '-', 
           transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
```

We thereby mimic the exact same behaviour as `axvline` uses, i.e. to use the data transform for the x value and the axes transform for the y value. Axes coordinates range from 0 to 1 within the axes, hence using those values will always let the line start at one end of the y axis and reach to the other, no matter its data range.

Comment: another crazy matplotlib magic trick  thanks! what happens here exactly?

Comment: I added a little explanation. Basically this does the same as `axvline` does in that it uses axes coordinates for the vertical direction.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Great answer! I'm interested in this `transform` concept. Where can I find documentation for this? And may I ask why it uses xaxis rather than yaxis transform here? Is that because they are x axis gridlines?

Comment: @Y.Luo The xaxis is the axis that has the data along its extent and is positionned at y=0 in axes coordinates. That is what is used here as well. There is a [Matplotlib transformations tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) which should cover most of what you need to know.

Comment: How is this not the default behavior for when ymin and ymax are not provided?!

Comment: Wow, another magic incantation in the bag :) THX!